# data transformations in scala/park

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
brand,month,price
abc,jan, - \n 
abc,feb, 29  \n
abc,mar, -   \n
abc,apr, 45.23  \n
bb-c,jan, 34  \n
bb-c,feb,-35  \n
bb-c,mar, - \n
```

sum(price) groupby(brand)

challenges

```
1)csv file available in xl sheet
2)trim the extra spaces in price
3)replace non-numeric(" -   ") with zero
4)sum the price group by brand
```

--read the csv file to df1
--changed the price data type string to double
--created registered temp table on df1
--but still facing issue with trim and 
--replace the zero for non numeric

can someone please help me on this issue.

Comment: input file will be like below
brand,month,price
abc,jan, -  

abc,feb, 29
abc,mar, -
abc,apr, 45.23
bb-c,jan, 34
bb-c,feb,-35
bb-c,mar, -

Comment: can you update with all the things you've mentined as you did. `--read the csv file to df1
--changed the price data type string to double
--created registered temp table on df1
--but still facing issue with trim and
--replace the zero for non numeric`

Comment: thanks for quick reply... I tried df.translate, df.regexp_replace and also trying to do with register temp table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Theoretical explaining :**

A simple use of *sqlContext to read the csv file*, *regexp_replace inbuilt function to replace the strings to doubles (casting)* and *groupBy and sum aggregation* should get you your desired output,

**Programmatically explaining :**

```
//1)csv file available in xl sheet
val df = sqlContext
  .read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", true)
  .load("path to the csv file")

df.show(false)
  //+-----+-----+------+
  //|brand|month|price |
  //+-----+-----+------+
  //|abc  |jan  | -    |
  //|abc  |feb  | 29   |
  //|abc  |mar  | -    |
  //|abc  |apr  | 45.23|
  //|bb-c |jan  | 34   |
  //|bb-c |feb  |-35   |
  //|bb-c |mar  | -    |
  //+-----+-----+------+  

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
//2)trim the extra spaces in price
//3)replace non-numeric(" -   ") with zero
df.withColumn("price", regexp_replace(col("price"), "[\\s+a-zA-Z- :]", "").cast("double"))
//4)sum the price group by brand    
    .groupBy("brand")
    .agg(sum("price").as("price_sum"))
    .show(false)
//+-----+-----------------+
//|brand|price_sum        |
//+-----+-----------------+
//|abc  |74.22999999999999|
//|bb-c |69.0             |
//+-----+-----------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: HI, I used this code but the problem is price column(xl) sheet contains comma ("1,345") due to that if the price exceed 999 then this code makes it as null. please suggest to overcome this problem

Comment: then include comma (`,`) as well in the regex as `[\\s+a-zA-Z- :,]` and you should be fine

Comment: if i replace "," with "" and then execute your code working... thanks a lot for help..

Comment: great to hear that @chalapathipothuraju